# Stop Activity before displaying in Android in App Widget

Tags: java, android, android-appwidget

I use a settings activity for my App Widget. The settings Activity has the following "Create" method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if (!isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(),"You're offline. Turn Internet on before", 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
...
```

I would like to stop the Activity before even something is displayed but to put the `isNetworkAvailable(this)` before the SetContentView doesn't work. The activity flickers for a while and then stops.
I would like to execute this check before the App Widget executes the "Intent" and before the Activity even appears (displays) but because of the App Widget architecture I don't see a quick way to do it.

Comment: is this the only way???...i think you can prevent user from getting inside this activity from previous activity if there is no internet....this will be a easier solution....

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your app theme to

```
android:Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
```

and use

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if (!isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "You're offline. Turn Internet on before",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
        return;
    }

    setTheme(R.style.your_theme)
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);

    ...
}
```